# How FileAttributes.Encrypted work in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file-attributes

I didn't find any example on google... Can anyone show how it works? And when folders and files will be encrypted how to decrypt them?

Link:
[FileAttributes Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `FileAttributes.Encrypted` flag tells you whether a file or folder has been encrypted by the NTFS file system. This option is available to users by right-clicking a file, selecting Properties, then clicking the Advanced button. There is an option "Encrypt contents to secure data" which is what the `FileAttributes.Encrypted` flag corresponds to.

You can use the `File.Encrypt` / `File.Decrypt` methods to encrypt or decrypt a file or folder. Note that you can only decrypt something that was encrypted by the current user.

You can use the [`System.IO.File.GetAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getattributes?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to get the `FileAttributes` from a file.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the following piece of code for File encryption identification:

```
FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes("C:\testfile.txt");
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.Encrypted) == FileAttributes.Encrypted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted file");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not Encrypted file");
}
```

Happy Coding...