# Check if File is encrypted or not

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, rijndaelmanaged

As per this [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26085/File-Encryption-and-Decryption-in-C), I have encrypted and decrypted file. 
At the end of the code, I am setting file attribute as `Encrypted`.

```
fsIn.Close();
cs.Close();
fsCrypt.Close();
// Mark the file as Encrypted
File.SetAttributes(outputFile, File.GetAttributes(outputFile) | FileAttributes.Encrypted);
```

and when I am done with decrypt.

```
// Mark the file Decrypted
File.SetAttributes(outputFile, File.GetAttributes(outputFile) & ~FileAttributes.Encrypted);
```

And here is how I am checking:

```
public static bool IsFileEncrypted(string filePath)
{
   FileAttributes attributes = File.GetAttributes(filePath);
   return (attributes & FileAttributes.Encrypted) == FileAttributes.Encrypted;
}
```

The problem is, variable `attributes` shows only `Archive` attribute.

How I can check whether File is encrypted or not? Is there any other solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12875282/1663001 Note that attribute is whether the file system has encrypted the file, not you.

Comment: Have you checked that the file gets encrypted? May be its stored on a filesystem that does not support encryption?

Comment: I need to check it through file system?

Comment: Yes and no. Depending on what you want. If you encrypt the file with AES or rijndael you can choose a password and there is also no need to set the encrypted flag. Or you let the OS do the encryption, then you use - if i remember correctly - `File.Encrypt`. By that you can't specify a password and the encrypted file can only be used/decrypted by the user-account that has encrypted the file.

Comment: Ok, using `File.Encrypt` was causing some exception notifying some certificate is invalid or expired.